# ExecutorService's shutdown() doesn't wait until all threads will be finished

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java-threads

I have a code where 4 threads run at the same time. I want to wait until all these 4 threads will be finished. And only after that to continue the app flow.

I tried two approaches:

1. [**`Thread#join()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--), this approach works as expected. The code, which comes after `join()` is executed only after all threads are finished.
2. [**`ExecutorService#shutdown()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--), this technique allows executing code, which comes after `shutdown()` even if not all threads are finished.

Code sample:

```java
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpuCoresNum);

for (int i = 0; i < cpuCoresNum; i++) {

    service.submit(() -> {
        try {
            foo(); // some long execution function
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

service.shutdown();

System.out.println("We're done! All threads are finished!");
```

Why don't `submit()` and `shutdown()` wait until all threads will be finished and prints *«We're done! All threads are finished!»* right after call of `service.shutdown();`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is available in the [`ExecutorService.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) Javadoc:

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use `awaitTermination` to do that.

If you want to wait for the threads to finish work you have the following options:

- get `Future` instances returned by `submit()` and call `get()` on every `Future` instance
- after calling `shutdown` on `service` call `awaitTermination` on `service` until it returns `true`
- instead of calling `submit` on `service` add your `Runnable` instances to a `java.util.List` and pass this list to the `invokeAll` method called on `service`

Comment: My threads don't return any value, thus, the second option seems to be more relevant.

Comment: @MikeB. `submit` returns a `Future` regardless whether you pass a `Runnable` or `Callable`, in both cases calling `get()` on a `Future` waits for the thread to complete its work. Before calling `awaitTermination` you have to call `shutdown`.

Comment: `awaitTermination()` requires some timeout to specify but in my case I don't know how much time it should take, thus, what value I have to specify as a `timeout` in order to assure that al threads will be finished correctly and not forced to stop due to `timeout`? From documentation: *«Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, **whichever happens first**.»*

Comment: Another option I would add for waiting until all of the executions are finished would be to give each thread a reference to a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which is initialized with the number of threads. Call `latch.await()` in your main thread and have the worker threads call `latch.countDown()` when they're finished.

Comment: @MikeB. You can pass a very large number as a timeout e.g. `Long.MAX_VALUE` however it is always good to provide a timeout as your code can always block/deadlock that is why the JDK designers made this attribute mandatory, I guess.

Comment: Waiting on a single `Future` does not guaranty that *all* jobs are finished. So the first bullet is not a real option.

Comment: @Holger of course when you call `get` on a single `Future` it only guarantees this `Future` is completed. I have updated the answer to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Recommended way from oracle documentation page of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```

`shutdown():`  Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

`shutdownNow():`Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

In above example, if your tasks are taking more time to complete, you can change if condition to while condition

Replace

```
if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

with

```
 while(!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
     Thread.sleep(60000);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @[Adam Siemion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345933/adam-siemion) suggestions, here is a final code:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpuCoresNum);

int itNum = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < cpuCoresNum; i++) {

    int treadID = itNum++;

    service.submit(() -> {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread_#" + treadID);
        try {
            foo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

// wait until all threads will be finished
service.shutdown();
try {
    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution